# Spring - Proxying Behind the Scenes

Tags: spring, transactions, proxy

What happens behind the scene when We Proxy a object. Say for example i say that a bean id = "bookService" refers to the class TransactionProxyFactoryBean of Spring.

The target attribute of the TransactionProxyFactoryBean points to BookServiceImpl class. So BookServiceImpl (Which is an implementation of the interface BookService) is getting proxied.
But what happens here? Does this TransactionProxyFacotoryBean Class extends the target that is getting proxied?

If so, will the TransactionProxyFactoryBean subtype itself from the BookServiceImpl (implementation) or the BookService (Interface)?

Answer (score 0):

The TransactionProxyFactoryBean will create a proxy. It won't itself be a proxy.

This proxy will handle the calls to your bean and, for the methods that you have configured to have transactions applied, will call the TransactionInterceptor which will start the transaction, call your bean's method, then end the transaction.

If you have proxyTargetClass="true" then the proxy will be a subtype of the class (using CGLIB). Otherwise the proxy will be a subtype of the interface that the target class implements.